# Need user plugin which enables having users without them logging into wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a plugin which will enable to me to have user profiles which are not also WordPress users. The reason for this is that I don't want the users to be able to see the admin toolbar. I still will need those users to create and post content.

Does anyone know if this exists? Or, any advice on how to remove the admin toolbar from showing for non-admins would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: what sort of user that person will be are you developing any premium selling or whatever courses or just to make sure the user should not have access

Answer (score 0):

The function checks the permissions of the user and if they have admin permissions then they can see the admin bar

Here are the links to the corresponding functions used:

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/
>
> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/show_admin_bar/
>
> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/

```
function remove_admin_bar() {
      if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
        show_admin_bar(true);
      }
      else{
        show_admin_bar(false);
      }
};
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');
```